# why use a "body h1" selector instead of "h1"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What's the use of the css selector `body h1` instead of simply `h1`? can there be `h1` tags anywhere else than within `body`?

Comment: No, there can't. The addition of `body` might be a specificity hack, or something else.

Comment: The "body h1" slector is stronger than just "h1" selector, so rules declared in "h1" selector can be overwritten by more specific seletor as "body h1". Althought it is better to use classes.

Answer (score 3):

`body h1` has higher [specificity (docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than just `h1`.

That's the only difference (in a valid html page at least).

Answer (score 1):

In practice, there's no difference other than the specificity of the selector you're using.

`h1 {}` will select all `h1` elements.

`body h1` will still select all `h1` elements, but only those inside a `body` tag (which of course, they should always be).

If you have `h1 { color:red }` and `body h1 { color:blue }` then the higher specificity, `blue`, will supercede `red`.

This is more useful when you're dealing with nested DOM elements. E.g. `ul li h1 { color:green }`